# Disappearing \, 'file not found' in Python

Tags: python, file-not-found

I'm struggling to find a solution for this problem. 'File not found' seems to be a common problem, but I can find anything referencing a disappearing \ in the console.

**Code**

```
fp = r"\Data\Exercise2\addresses.txt"

data = pd.read_csv(fp, sep=';')
```

**Error**

> IOError: File
>   Users\Kaitlyn\Desktop\GeoPython\Data\Exercise2ddresses.txt does not
>   exist

Eventually I got around the problem by putting the file directly into working directory folder. I tried using the absolute file path, checking/setting the wd, but that didn't work either - same error. I'm new to Python and trying to understand what could cause the error message to list the incorrect filepath?

Thanks

Comment: Just change `\ to `/

Comment: What sort of machine are you trying to run this on? The backslashes say Windows but the fact that your root folder is called "Users" is rather odd.

Comment: Or you can use \\a

Comment: Also, if you want to use the relative path, remove the first (back)slash.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the problem. I'm getting `FileNotFoundError: File b'\\Data\\Exercise2\\addresses.txt' does not exist`, which is escaped correctly. Which OS, python version and pandas version are you using?